# Выравнивание текста, внутри комбобокса

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста. У меня есть комбобокс. В него выводится адрес магазина и его Юр.лицо. Данные формируются из SQL запроса. Запрашиваю Адрес магазина, ip, юрлицо И добавляю в Лист "Адрес + | + Юрлицо"

Выглядит это так:
Адрес магазина 1 | ООО дидкпик
Адрес магаааааазина 2 | ООО дидкпик
Адрес магааазина 3 | ООО дидкпик
Адрес магааазинаааа 4 | ООО дидкпик
Адрес маааагазинаааа 5 | ООО дидкпик
Адрес маагазинаааа 6 | ООО дидкпик

И так 40 раз. Везде разные адреса, везде разные юрлица. Выглядит это все - отвратительно и нечитабельно.

И я бы хотел, чтобы Адрес прижимался к левому краю комбобокса, а юрлицо к правой части. Вопрос: Возможно ли так? Если нет, то какой может быть аналог, чтобы был с выпадающим списком? Спасибо большое

Comment: Жаль что формы, наверное свой рендер айтема придется делать, а в WPF бы такое  за 10 минут сделать можно было. Визуально советую в 2 строки. Вторую строчку сделать шрифтом посветлее и поменьше. В 1С такие штуки сделаны таблицами, а не комбобоксами.

Comment: ну если вы хотите именно в `combobox`, то можете просто подобавлять пустых пробелов нужным строкам (для этого нужно просто найти максимальную длину адреса и всем остальным адресам добавить пробелов столько, что бы была максимальная длина), но тут будет не идеально ровно и зависить от шрифта

Comment: У вас явно табличные данные. Для их вывода используйте `DataGridView` и дело с концом... / Если непременно хочется застрять на текстбоксе (ох-ах, так сложно поменять один контрол на другой!), задайте ему моноширинный шрифт и используйте стандартное форматирование с указанием длины поля.